# typeof cannot resolve symbol

Tags: c#, typeof

In the following class I get a compile error on `typeof`.
Why can't the compiler resolve the type?

```
public class TestTypeOf
{
    public struct Teststruct
    {
        public int d1;
        public int d2;
    }
    Teststruct cds;

    public Teststruct ToString (IntPtr lParam)
    {
        var t = typeof(cds);    // cannot resolve symbol 'cds'
        cds.d1 = 1;
        cds.d2 = 2;
        return cds;
    }

    public TestTypeOf ()
    {
        cds = new Teststruct();
    }

}
```

Comment: You're supposed to pass it a type: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx

Comment: OK, got it: thanks!

Comment: Why the (unexplained) down-votes? This is counter-intuitive and in fact opposite to the normal convention in c-based languages.

Comment: I didn't downvote, however you could have easily found/read the documentation for it.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, thanks for the feedback but the documentation is vague: it should highlight that its out of step with everybody else. That would make it less confusing.

Comment: Everybody else? Like what, Java?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli well, javascript at least

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `typeof` operator works with types directly at compile time. For instance `typeof(DateTime)`. If you want the type of an object, use the `GetType()` method. It derives from `Object`, so it will be available on any object.

```
var hello = "Hello, world!";
var type = hello.GetType();
```